# Trying to find amount of words from input file

Tags: java, while-loop

I am trying to read in information from an external file and print to the screen different stats about them. I was able to successfully track down the amount of lines and paragraphs but ran into trouble trying to find the total amount of words.

I noticed that when I take the second while loop and put it first, it gives me the correct amount of words but the wrong lines and paragraphs, but when I run it as it is now, it gives me the correct lines and paragraphs but the wrong words.

I would really appreciate your help in figuring out why this is so. Thank you!

```
int x = 0, words = 0, y = 0;
System.out.print("Name of the input file: ");
in = kbd.nextLine().toLowerCase();
System.out.println(" ");

// Set up connection to the input file
Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader(in));

// Set up connection to an output file
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("datacopy.txt"));
int lineNum = 0;

while (input.hasNextLine()) {

    String line;
    line = input.nextLine();

    if (line.length() == 0) {
        x++;
    }
    output.println(line + "\n");
    lineNum++;

}
while (input.hasNext()) {
    String line = input.next();
    words++;
}

System.out.println("Words: " + words);
System.out.println("Lines: " + lineNum);
System.out.println("Paragraphs " + --x);
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println("Output file datacopy.txt created.");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to re-initialize your `input` in each loop :

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader(in));

//loop1

input = new Scanner(new FileReader(in));//re-initialize it again

//loop2
```

Because in the second loop, your loop not start from the beginning, it will start from the end-point of the first loop.

Comment: @s24569 This solution definitely works, but it reads through the file twice. This doubles the amount of work, making it very inefficient for large files, especially if they are located on remote drives.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that both loops below require the `input` to be positioned at the start of file:

```
while (input.hasNextLine()) // count lines

while(input.hasNext()) // count words
```

Although "rewinding" the file and starting from the beginning is possible, it is not optimal. It is better to read the file line-by-line, and count words as you go.

Using the `line` variable from the `while (input.hasNextLine())` loop, split it into individual words, and add their number to the running total:

```
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = input.nextLine();
    output.println(line + "\n");
    lineNum++;
    if(line.length() == 0){
        x++;
        continue;
    }
    words += line.split("\\s+").length;
}
```

Comment: This is a more efficient way of processing the input file